# Android Databinding with menus

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm testing out the new Data Binding feature built into Android. I've successfully done simple binding to text views, and even two-way binding, and binding a `List<>` to a `RecyclerView`. Now I want to test it with a menu view, but when I add a layout XML file to the menu folder, I see the menu and the item I added, but when I just wrap the contents of that menu view with a `<layout>` tag, it says the "Element layout must be declared". I didn't have to make a special declaration on the other layouts I've tested. which suggests that you can't use it with layouts in the menu folder. Is that the case, or am I missing something?

Comment: This may be a bug that was fixed. The `<tag ../>` was broken in earlier versions. Which version of the android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Comment: I'm getting the same with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2. I'm not sure that there's any documentation saying one can or cannot make this work.

Comment: That is correct. Data binding does not work with menu resources. However, I was able to create a data bound menu item using an action view. You can find the full solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43554495/2685955

Comment: @botnerd, thanks for the answer. I took a look at your linked answer, but honestly, this being a little over a year ago, I moved on, and decided that Android's current data-binding feature isn't quite primetime, and since Android isn't my main focus for development work, I can't honestly say if your solution is 'the' answer to this question, so I can't marked it as such, but did upvote your answer, and appreciate your trying to be helpful. Keep it up!