# Side Menu menu items with data binding

Tags: android, xml, view, navigation-drawer, android-databinding

I have a situation here I get a list of booleans based on which I hide and show the side menu items I need to remove boilerplate code and need to bind my side menu menu items based on the data I receive but I don't know how to bind `side_menu.xml` which is menu with my object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_profile"
                android:title="Profile"
                android:checkable="false"
                 />
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_doctorlist"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_my_doctors"
                android:title="My Doctors"
                android:checkable="false"/>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_orders"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_my_orders"
                android:title="Orders"
                android:visible="false"
                android:checkable="false"/>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_searchDoc"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_search_doctors"
                android:title="Search Doctors"
                android:checkable="false"/>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_myappointments"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_my_appointments"
                android:title="Appointments"
                android:checkable="false"
                />
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_instant_doctors"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_instant_doctor"
                android:title="Instant Doctor"
                android:checkable="false"
                android:visible="false"
                />
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_healthrecord"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_my_health_record"
                android:title="Medical Records"
                android:checkable="false"/>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_labtests"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_lab_tests"
                android:title="Lab Tests"
                android:visible="false"
                android:checkable="false"/>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_invoice"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_invoices"
                android:title="Invoices"
                android:visible="false"
                android:checkable="false"/>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_chat"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_help"
                android:title="Help"
                android:checkable="false"/>
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_logout"
                android:title="Login / Sign Up"
                android:checkable="false"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Here below is the menu I need to hide and show some items based on my objects data so how do I bind it ? Using data binding.

Comment: Databinding is not available for menu till now, AFAIK. But there is a workaround. Check below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39283632/6891563